# Normalise trainingset and testingset using libsvm easy.py

Tags: python, scale, normalization, libsvm

I am very near to svm. I have two files `trainingSeta.data` and `testingSeta.data`. these fines are in the correct format as stated on the FAQ. i am trying to normalize the data in both files. but having trouble understanding the guides at to scale them.

it says i should use `svm-scale` but it doesnt seem to be working. both files are in the same folder as `svm-scale`. on the guides their files are something.scale and something.t.scale. I dont understand how to get my files into that format and how to normalize my data. should i use `svm-scale` or `easy.py`

any help would be appreciated.

i worked it out.

how do i close a question?

Answer (score 0):

svm-scale can do both

- or scan data for for feature range, scale data and write range file.
- use an existing range file to scale data

from [libsvm faq](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html)

```
Q: Should I scale training and testing data in a similar way?
Yes, you can do the following:
> svm-scale -s scaling_parameters train_data > scaled_train_data
> svm-scale -r scaling_parameters test_data > scaled_test_data
```

what I am missing in the FAQ is - you **must** use the same range file for both, test and training data.